# Sequence of methods getting called when push notification comes in

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, push-notification

What is the first method which gets called when a push notification comes and we tap on "View" button of the alert?

I wanted to understand the flow because I want to present the modal view for my notification and that modal will be on top of my root view controller so I want to understand the sequence of methods which gets called when notification comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`
2. `didReceiveLocalNotification`